# Listview Delete Item Index source is in use wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, items

I wanna delete items from my `observablecollection`

```
ObservableCollection<GetterSetter> _getterSetter = new ObservableCollection<GetterSetter>();

public ObservableCollection<GetterSetter> showList
    {
        get { return this._getterSetter; }
    }
```

So my xaml file is like this,

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged" Foreground="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListViewItem,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single">
<ListView.View>
     <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="180" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ShowName}"/>
     </GridView>
```

and i have a ShowName getter setter in here,

```
private string _showName;

public String ShowName{
    get { return _showName; }
    set
    {
      if (value == _showName) return;
      _showName = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
```

I wanna delete the selected item like this and it gives me an error,

```
listView.Items.Remove(listView.SelectedItems[0]);
showList.RemoveAt(listView.Items.IndexOf(listView.SelectedItems[0]));
```

I also tried this

```
var delete = SelectedListViewItem;
listView.Items.Remove(delete);
```

and both gave me this error,

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

by the way `GetterSetter` is my cs file where is my third code snippet lies,

```
public GetterSetter SelectedListViewItem
    {
        get { return _selectedListViewItem; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _selectedListViewItem)) return;
            _selectedListViewItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as the error says, do it from ItemsSource directly.  To do that, you need to case the ItemsSource to it's type and then do the remove.

```
if(SelectedListViewItem != null)
{
    // EDIT: Typo in the lambda for FirstOrDefault
    var delete = showList.FirstOrDefault(x => SelectedListViewItem.ShowName == x.ShowName);
    if(delete != null)
    {
        ((ObservableCollection<GetterSetter>)listView.ItemsSource).Remove(delete);
    }
}
```

Edit: The NULL monster is getting you.

Comment: Now it gives me "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." at this line of code, `showNameBox.Text = showList[listView.Items.IndexOf(listView.SelectedItems[0])].ShowName;`

Comment: What exactly is SelectedListViewItem?  Where is it defined?

Comment: It's defined in xaml code you can see it in second code snippet

Comment: It's binding to a property, but I need to know what TYPE that property is.

Comment: Okay I see I edited my question you can see it on last code snippet

Comment: It's still gives me index was out of range error :( even with the null code

Comment: What property of GetterSetter is your primary key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97551/discussion-between-louni-and-the-sharp-ninja).